# nginx + WordPress: Proper user/file permissions for SFTP + auto update?

Tags: php, wordpress, ubuntu, nginx, sftp

I used [this](http://wordimpress.com/aws-ec2-rds-s3-cloudfront-nginx-wordpress-tutorial-roundup/) guide to install nginx and WordPress on a Ubuntu VPS. The guide instructs you to set the owner of the `/var/www` directory to `nginx:nginx`. When I use SFTP, I log in with the name `ubuntu`, but this name doesn't have permission to write any of the files that `nginx` owns.

My question is... what would be the ideal way to do the following:

1. To grant user `ubuntu` proper permission to write to files in `/var/www` via SFTP
2. Keep `nginx` the owner of `/var/www` so WordPress can continue to auto-update files

Would it be as simple as adding `ubuntu` to the `nginx` group? My concern is security, and I'm wondering what would be the most secure way of accomplishing the above.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add new (or edit existed www.conf) php pool here /etc/php5/fpm/pool.d/*.conf to work with any user+group impersonation. [For example](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/articles/how-to-optimize-nginx-with-php-pools-on-an-ubuntu-13-04-vps).