# LEMP + wordpress file permissions to be able to edit, upgrade and use sftp client

Tags: wordpress, file, nginx, permissions, sftp

I am trying to manage file permissions on a debian webserver that runs nginx, so that wordpress can edit, upload and upgrade without having to use ftp. I also want to be able to login using sftp with my user account.

I am aware of the fact that this question has been asked before, see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22463192/nginx-wordpress-proper-user-file-permissions-for-sftp-auto-update)
or [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1113691/a-general-linux-file-permissions-question-apache-and-wordpress), but following the steps in those answers hasn't been satisfying. The setup currently looks as follows:

- The wordpress folder is in `/var/www/html/`
- I made a new user ("user") and group ("group"). The server user is
  "www-data".
- All files in the wordpress folder are owned by user:group.
- Both "user" and "www-data" are set to belong to "group".
- I changed file and folder permissions as follows:

  ```
  find /var/www/html/ -type d -exec chmod 2775 {} +

  find /var/www/html/ -type f -exec chmod 664 {} +
  ```
- I set the default umask to 0002.

I would have thought this should work, but currently I can edit and upload files from within wordpress, but not update wordpress, functions or themes.

- It also does not work with "group" set as default group for "user" and/or "www-data" (by editing `/etc/passwd`).

Alternatively, I made all files in `/var/www/html/` owned by user:www-data, but also without success.

The only way I seem to get wordpress to update without ftp is by making the wordpress-folder and all its files owned by "www-data". Unfortunately, the result of that is that I cannot upload files using an sftp-client (because the target is now a folder that is not owned by "user").

How can this be? As far as I understand these steps should give wordpress the proper permissions, but something still is wrong.

Your help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Yes! Figured it out. You need to specify the group that is used by the server in (in my case) /etc/php5/fpm/pool.d/www.conf. I commented out the specified group so that it uses the default group. Than restart the service. I will provide the details later, when I'm happy with final setup.

Answer (score 1):

On a debian server I followed these steps. It might not be the most secure solution as I read [here](http://themesforge.com/performance/configuring-nginx-php5-fpm-and-user-permissions/?doing_wp_cron=1410970565.4835669994354248046875), but it works (wordpress can edit, upload and upgrade - and I can upload using sftp).

- Create a new user "user"
- Create a new group "group" (you can choose to use www-data as group as well)
- Add user and www-data to group

  > ```
  > usermod -G group user
  > usermod -G group www-data
  > ```
- Check group numerical id in `/etc/group`
  e.g. group:x:**1002**
- Change default group of www-data and user in `/etc/passwd`
  e.g. user:x:1001:**1002**:...
- In `/etc/php5/fpm/pool.d/www.conf` (in my case) change `group=www-data` to `;group=www-data`. Now nginx will use the default group of www-data which we just set to "group". Reload service (php5-fpm).
- Recursively change owner of your wordpress folder to user:group

  > ```
  > chown -R user:group /var/www/html
  > ```
- Change permissions in your wordpress folder (The 2 is to assign new files to the parent folder's group)

  > ```
  > find /var/www/html/ -type d -exec chmod 2775 {} +
  > find /var/www/html/ -type f -exec chmod 664 {} +
  > ```
- Change umask to `UMASK 0002` in `/etc/login.defs`
- In wordpress, enforce direct upload (so no ftp) by adding `define('FS_METHOD','direct');` to wp-config.php. ***In my case, this was an essential step.***
- To get things working, I needed to reboot.

Answer (score 1):

I ran into this issue and I figured that I would share how I fixed it on `Ubuntu` running `PHP 7` in case it can help someone. I adapted the following after reading [this](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-optimize-nginx-with-php-pools-on-an-ubuntu-13-04-vps) article that outlines how it is done with `PHP 5`.

Nginx needs to be optimized with PHP pools in order to give ownership of files and folders to users.

First, you need to create a new PHP-FPM memory pool. Do this by copying the default memory pool and renaming it with the user that you want to associate it with:

```
sudo cp /etc/php/7.0/fpm/pool.d/www.conf /etc/php/7.0/fpm/pool.d/username.conf
```

Edit the file:

```
sudo nano /etc/php/7.0/fpm/pool.d/username.conf
```

Go through the file and change `username` in the following locations:

```
; Start a new pool named 'www'.
; the variable $pool can we used in any directive and will be replaced by the
; pool name ('www' here)
[username]


; Note: The user is mandatory. If the group is not set, the default user's group
;       will be used.
user = username


listen = /run/php/php7.0-fpm.username.sock
```

Now you need to update your server block(s). You will need to adjust to the correct sockets to allow access to the newly created pool.

Open your server configuration file:

```
sudo nano /etc/nginx/sites-available/default
```

Or if you setup server blocks (virtual hosts), then:

```
sudo nano /etc/nginx/sites-available/example.com
```

Edit the following line and replace `username`:

```
fastcgi_pass unix:/run/php/php7.0-fpm.username.sock;
```

Finally, restart Nginx:

```
sudo service nginx restart
```